# bash: How to break the while loop which reads data from sqlpus

Tags: arrays, oracle, bash, while-loop, sqlplus

I'm trying to read output from sqlplus in the loop

```
while read -r line; do
  [commands] 
done < <(sqlplus -s ${user}/${pwd}@${database} @query.sql)
```

And all commands in the cycle work properly but loop isn't being closed!

I've tried already several solutions, such as

```
done=0
while read -r line; do
  [commands] 
  if [ "$done" -ne 0 ]; then
      break
  fi
done < <(sqlplus -s ${user}/${pwd}@${database} @query.sql)
```

or

```
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  [commands] 
done < <(sqlplus -s ${user}/${pwd}@${database} @query.sql)
```

But they don't work as well.

+also I've checked that last line of result set has \n\r symbol

If anybody can help me understand why I'm having listed above issues or suggest to use some other approach - I'll be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A process substitution expands to the name of a special file or FIFO from which the output of the specified command can be read.  It does not necessarily follow that end-of-file will be detected when no more program output is available; that's certainly not the behavior that would be expected from a FIFO.

I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.  You should be able to use an ordinary pipe instead of a process substitution for this task:

```
sqlplus -s ${user}/${pwd}@${database} @query.sql | while read -r line; do
  [commands] 
done
```

As long as `sqlplus` indeed does exit, `read` will detect EOF after it does so, causing the loop to exit.